# PowerPoint: Grouping is disabled for the selected shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm adding some shapes to the slide and group them together with the code provided.

```
' Inserting shapes like this
Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
Set sDesc = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, startX, picStartY, boxWidth, 20)

[...]

' Group shapes together
sld.Shapes.Range(Array(sBox.Name, sLogo.Name, sDesc.Name)).Group
```

But if there is a placeholder for shapes (see picture, not sure what the correct term is) on the slide I get an error saying that it can't be grouped. It seems like the shapes replace this placeholder and the error appears.

Any suggestions?

[image: Placeholder for shapes]

> Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)':
>
> Grouping is disabled for the selected shapes

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as the error message states (which may well be a first for VBA error messages!).  You cannot group placeholders with other shapes.

Comment: So is there any way I can insert the shapes without replacing the placeholder? It's not meant to replace anything, really.

Comment: The short answer to that would be "Don't include the name of the placeholder in the list of shapes you're creating an array from".  But it's not clear what you mean by "replacing the placeholder".

Comment: If I insert a shape, with VBA or by simply adding it through the GUI, it will remove the placeholder, which I think is causing the problem. However, I'm not sure how that can be the case if the placeholder is then removed. [Screenshots on imgur](http://imgur.com/a/84uuC) EDIT: To put it another way, I'm not adding a placeholder, so why does it try to group one?

Comment: If you add a picture to a slide with a content or image placeholder (as you've done in your screenshots), the image is "held" by the placeholder; the placeholder may seem to have disappeared, but it's still there. Select and delete the image:  the placeholder returns.  If you need to group the image with other shapes, copy it, paste special to get a new image, then delete the original.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg how can you check which shapes are possible to group?  For example grouping SmartArts are also impossible (because they are already some kind of special group). For example is there a property on a shape which indicates that it can be grouped? Or is there a list provided by Microsoft or a third party?

Comment: @SoonDead SmartArt shapes can be grouped, but again, not of they're within a placeholder; placeholders cannot be grouped. So to test if the shape is a placeholder, check it's .Type ... if the .Type = 14, it's a placeholder, so whatever's IN the placeholder can't be grouped.

Comment: I get the same error message in Word, where there are no placeholders. I tried to group (nest) two little rectangles in a big document (100 pages) and the error message showed up. I don't know why, since my test code worked fine. `Set shp3 = doc.shapes.Range(Array("outside", "inside")).Group`

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this - I was generating shapes and needed to group the ones I had generated.

Using shape names is really the only viable approach I could find.

ZOrderPosition looked good (and is the index number) but the number of shapes returned from ThisSlide.Shapes is not a full indexed collection of all the shapes (I think because the Shapes collection returned treats a shape with type group as a single shape and does not include its underlying shapes). E.g. the ZOrderPosition I got for a generated shape was 103 but the ThisSlide.Shapes collection only returned 57 shapes so indexing that for 103 threw an out of bounds exception.

I initially solved the problem by adding a generated shape number to the shape name which worked as long as I didn't run the routine twice (it was a VSTO add in) which ended up generating duplicate shape names.

The solution I found was to make every name unique by adding the shapes' .Top property as an integer to the shape name - e.g.

GeneratedShape.name = "added_" & cint(GeneratedShape.top) & AddedShapeNo

Comment: Yes, when you group several shapes, PPT creates a new shape whose .Type property = msoGroup or 6. You can't, as far as I know, group a shape or shapes from within a group with shapes that aren't part of the group, but you could collect the needed shapes in an array or collection. The routine that does that needs to use recursion to handle groups.